Bicep file case matching on json file
I have this bicep file that is loading a json content, but its encountering an error when the object case doesn't match.
name vs Name in this case.
Is there a way that I can have some sort case insensitive as they may be other json files or objects that have this scenario, bicep seems to not support transforming data directly.
ex.
policy_definition_insight_append_nsg_rule.json
{
  "**Name**": "Append-NSG-Rule",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "apiVersion": "2021-06-01",



bicep file:
var customPolicyDefinitionsArray = [
    {
        name: 'Append-NSG-Rule'
        libDefinition: json(loadTextContent('lib/policy_definitions/policy_definition_insight_append_nsg_rule.json'))
    }
]

resource policyDefinitions 'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions@2021-06-01' = [for policy in customPolicyDefinitionsArray: {
    name: policy.libDefinition.**name **

tried testing toLower, but it only transforms the name not the json object.
